# How do I get Prayer Webmail running on HTTPS?

Tags: ubuntu, dovecot, exim, webmail

I can't seem to get Prayer Webmail to run an https port.  I'm running Exim4+Dovecot on Ubuntu 16.04.2.

It works fine on the unsecure http port-- except that it's unsecure (I'm using port 8888 for http, and port 8843 for https).

The port is open in the firewall.  If I set up a socket on on 8843 I can connect to it, testing the firewall.

I've tried several different ports, so it's not that.

On running, I get no obvious errors.  I followed all the docs I can find, and it looks correct to me in the config file, but it will only open the http port.  If I disable the http port in prayer.cf it won't run as it says there or no ports configured to open.

It is able to load the .key and .crt files just fine (it will close with error if I change something so it can't).

Anybody know how to get it to run on https?

Here's my prayer.cf config:

```
prefix      = "/usr/share/prayer"
var_prefix  = "/var/run/prayer"

prayer_user           = "prayer"
prayer_group          = "nogroup"

prayer_background     = TRUE

file_perms            = 0640

directory_perms       = 0750





imapd_user_map      = ""

imapd_server        = localhost/notls

prefs_folder_name   = ".prayer"



accountd_user_map   = ""



accountd_timeout    = 2m


sieved_timeout      = 9m

sieve_maxsize       = 32k









hostname         = "example.com"

use_http_port    8888
use_https_port   8843

#ssl_default_port = 8843



fatal_dump_core = FALSE
log_debug  =  TRUE

fix_client_ipaddr = FALSE




limit_vm = 150m
recips_max_msg     = 250
recips_max_session = 1000
sending_allow_dir = "${var_prefix}/sending/allow"
sending_block_dir = "${var_prefix}/sending/block"



http_max_method_size = 32k
http_max_hdr_size    = 64k

http_max_body_size   = 15m

http_min_servers     = 4
http_max_servers     = 16
http_max_connections = 20

http_cookie_use_port = FALSE

http_timeout_idle    = 10s
http_timeout_icons   = 60s
http_timeout_session = 5m
icon_expire_timeout  = 7d





ssl_cert_file       = "/etc/prayer/server.crt"
ssl_privatekey_file = "/etc/prayer/server.key"

ssl_rsakey_lifespan = 15m
ssl_rsakey_freshen  = 15m

ssl_cipher_list = "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH:!EXP"

ssl_server_preference = T




session_idle_time       = 10m
session_timeout         = 30m
session_timeout_compose = 2h

stream_checkpoint       = T
stream_ping_interval    = 20m
stream_misc_timeout = 15m 

log_ping_interval  = 10m
db_ping_interval   = 30m

login_template      = "login"
login_banner        = "WebMAIL"
login_service_name  = "example.com"

list_addr_maxlen    = 30
list_subject_maxlen = 30
change_max_folders  = 20

use_ispell_language  british   "British English"
use_ispell_language  american  "American English"

draft_att_single_max = 10M
draft_att_total_max  = 10M

fix_from_address = FALSE

spam_purge_name = "spam_purge"
spam_purge_prefix = "# Spam Purge Timeout:"
spam_purge_timeout = 60


sendmail_path       = /usr/lib/sendmail


ispell_path         = /usr/bin/ispell





ssl_encouraged      = FALSE
ssl_redirect        = FALSE
ssl_required        = FALSE

icon_dir            = "$prefix/icons"
static_dir          = "$prefix/static"
bin_dir             = "/usr/sbin"
log_dir             = "/var/log/prayer"
lock_dir            = "$var_prefix"
socket_dir          = "$var_prefix/sockets"
socket_split_dir    = TRUE
init_socket_name    = init
ssl_session_dir     = "$var_prefix/ssl_scache"
tmp_dir             = "$var_prefix/tmp"
pid_dir             = "$var_prefix"




template_path = "/etc/prayer/templates"
template_set  = "old"
template_use_compiled = TRUE

template old  "Traditional"
template cam  "Cambridge House Style"


theme blue description           "Web Safe Blue"
theme blue fgcolor               "#000000"       # Black
theme blue fgcolor_link          "#0000ff"       # Dark    Blue
theme blue bgcolor               "#ccffff"       # Light   Blue 
theme blue bgcolor_banner        "#66ffff"       # Darkish Blue
theme blue bgcolor_row1          "#ccffff"       # Light   Blue
theme blue bgcolor_row2          "#99ffff"       # Middle  Blue
theme blue bgcolor_status        "#ffffcc"       # Yellow
theme blue bgcolor_status_none   "#ccffcc"       # Green
theme blue fgcolor_quote1        "#800000"       # Brick Red
theme blue fgcolor_quote2        "#008000"       # Green
theme blue fgcolor_quote3        "#000080"       # Blue
theme blue fgcolor_quote4        "#ff0000"       # Orange

theme green description          "Web Safe Green"
theme green fgcolor              "#000000"       # Black
theme green fgcolor_link         "#0000ff"       # Dark    Blue
theme green bgcolor              "#ccffcc"       # Light   Green
theme green bgcolor_banner       "#99ff99"       # Middle  Green
theme green bgcolor_row1         "#ccffcc"       # Light   Green
theme green bgcolor_row2         "#99ff99"       # Middle  Green
theme green bgcolor_status       "#ffffcc"       # Yellow
theme green bgcolor_status_none  "#ccffff"       # Light   Blue
theme green fgcolor_quote1       "#800000"       # Brick Red
theme green fgcolor_quote2       "#008000"       # Green
theme green fgcolor_quote3       "#000080"       # Blue
theme green fgcolor_quote4       "#ff0000"       # Orange

theme yellow description         "Web Safe Yellow"
theme yellow fgcolor             "#000000"       # Black
theme yellow fgcolor_link        "#0000ff"       # Dark   Blue
theme yellow bgcolor             "#ffffcc"       # Light  Yellow
theme yellow bgcolor_banner      "#ffff66"       # Middle Yellow
theme yellow bgcolor_row1        "#ffffcc"       # Light  Yellow
theme yellow bgcolor_row2        "#ffff66"       # Middle Yellow
theme yellow bgcolor_status      "#ccffff"       # Light  Blue
theme yellow bgcolor_status_none "#ccffcc"       # Green
theme yellow fgcolor_quote1      "#800000"       # Brick Red
theme yellow fgcolor_quote2      "#008000"       # Green
theme yellow fgcolor_quote3      "#000080"       # Blue
theme yellow fgcolor_quote4      "#ff0000"       # Orange

theme gray description          "Shades of Gray" # NB: Not Web safe!
theme gray fgcolor              "#000000"        # Black
theme gray fgcolor_link         "#0000ff"        # Dark   Blue
theme gray bgcolor              "#eeeeee"        # Light  gray
theme gray bgcolor_banner       "#cccccc"        # Dark   gray
theme gray bgcolor_row1         "#eeeeee"        # Light  gray
theme gray bgcolor_row2         "#dddddd"        # Middle gray
theme gray bgcolor_status       "#ffffcc"        # Yellow
theme gray bgcolor_status_none  "#ccffcc"        # Green
theme gray fgcolor_quote1        "#800000"       # Brick Red
theme gray fgcolor_quote2        "#008000"       # Green
theme gray fgcolor_quote3        "#000080"       # Blue
theme gray fgcolor_quote4        "#ff0000"       # Orange

theme high description          "High Constrast" # Yuck!
theme high fgcolor              "#000000"        # Black
theme high fgcolor_link         "#0000ff"        # Dark  Blue
theme high bgcolor              "#ffffff"        # Very, very white
theme high bgcolor_banner       "#cccccc"        # Dark gray
theme high bgcolor_row1         "#ffffff"        # Very, very white
theme high bgcolor_row2         "#cccccc"        # Dark gray
theme high bgcolor_status       "#ffffcc"        # Yellow
theme high bgcolor_status_none  "#ccffcc"        # Green
theme high fgcolor_quote1        "#800000"       # Brick Red
theme high fgcolor_quote2        "#008000"       # Green
theme high fgcolor_quote3        "#000080"       # Blue
theme high fgcolor_quote4        "#ff0000"       # Orange

theme help description          "Default Help Text theme"
theme help fgcolor              "#000000"        # Black
theme help fgcolor_link         "#0000ff"        # Dark Blue
theme help bgcolor              "#ffffcc"        # Yellow
theme help bgcolor_banner       "#66ffff"        # Darkish Blue
theme help bgcolor_row1         "#ccffff"        # Light   Blue
theme help bgcolor_row2         "#99ffff"        # Middle  Blue
theme help bgcolor_status       "#ccffff"        # Light   Blue
theme help bgcolor_status_none  "#ccffcc"        # Green
theme help fgcolor_quote1        "#800000"       # Brick Red
theme help fgcolor_quote2        "#008000"       # Green
theme help fgcolor_quote3        "#000080"       # Blue
theme help fgcolor_quote4        "#ff0000"       # Orange

theme_default_main  = gray
theme_default_help  = help



confirm_logout      = TRUE
confirm_expunge     = FALSE
confirm_rm          = TRUE
expunge_on_exit     = FALSE

msgs_per_page       = 10
msgs_per_page_max   = 50
msgs_per_page_min   = 4

abook_per_page      = 10
abook_per_page_max  = 50
abook_per_page_min  = 4

suppress_dotfiles   = TRUE

maildir             = ""

use_namespace       = TRUE

personal_hierarchy  = ""

hiersep             = "/"

dualuse             = FALSE

postponed_folder    = "Drafts"
sent_mail_folder    = "Sent"


ispell_language     = "american"

small_cols          = 80
small_rows          = 14
large_cols          = 80
large_rows          = 24

sort_mode           = ARRIVAL

sort_reverse        = FALSE

abook_sort_mode     = ORDERED

abook_sort_reverse        = FALSE

line_wrap_len       = 76

line_wrap_advanced  = FALSE

line_wrap_on_reply  = TRUE

line_wrap_on_spell  = TRUE

line_wrap_on_send   = TRUE

use_sent_mail       = TRUE

use_mark_persist    = FALSE

use_search_zoom     = TRUE

use_agg_unmark      = TRUE

use_icons           = TRUE

use_tail_banner     = TRUE

use_cookie          = TRUE

use_substitution    = FALSE

use_http_1_1        = TRUE

use_pipelining      = TRUE

use_persist         = TRUE

use_short           = TRUE

use_gzip            = TRUE

html_inline         = TRUE

html_remote_images  = FALSE

html_inline_auto    = TRUE

preserve_mimetype   = TRUE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay.  So it appears that prayer was in fact listening on the designated https port... interestingly, while testing I was using nmap to scan for open status, and the scans show closed whether from inside or out, but my browser connects and I'm able to login to prayer ove https on the designated port, yet it still shows closed on a scan.

How is this possible?

Comment: As a side note, nmap shows the http port as open (except now only from inside, as I just blocked it so it can't be accessed externally).